# Choosing step for Bezier curve drawing

Tags: graphics, bezier, polynomials

Bezier curve is a parametric curve, meaning that there is a paramater `t` at which one can evaluate the polynomials in order to find out the positions of points laying on the curve.

Polynomials for some common cases can be found at [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Specific_cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Specific_cases)

To draw a Bezier curve on screen, one could evaluate the polynomials from `0` to `1` at ever increasing `t` by tiny little steps. However, that would very wasteful because, in general, the parameter "space" does not correspond to screen "space", i.e. several little steps may fall onto just one pixel.

My question is: how to find the smallest step which increases Cartesian distance from previous point at least by 1 pixel?

To put it in other way: I would like to draw a Bezier curve on screen. How to choose the (uniform) step by which `t` should grow so that I never draw at one pixel more the once? I don't mind the "holes" when the `t` grows too quickly, I just don't want to redraw already drawn pixels.

**Edit**

By "how to find" I mean O(1). Yes, I could use [De Casteljau's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm) but I was hoping there is a way to "guess" the optimal `t` step quickly.

Comment: I don't think a uniform step is what you're after. As long as your curve spans a lot of pixels, I'd find the derivative with respect to `t` at each point, then increment `t` by the amount producing a derivative of at least one pixel (in either x or y). If the curve bends quickly relative to the pixel size this won't work.

Comment: Consider supporting http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74985/computer-graphics.

Comment: @lhf I just did, thanks for the suggestion. And thanks for Lua, too!

Answer (score 1):

The comment above (jozxyqk) gives you a hint. I would give it a try with a recursive binary division of the spline drawing.

Lets say you start with a coarse resolution of the parameter space (delta_t = 0.1), that gives you 11 points on the spline curve *s* , *s(t=0)*, *s(t=0.1)*, ..., *s(t=0.9)*, *s(t=1)*.
Calculate the distance between *s(t_i)* and *s(t_i+1)*. If it is >1 than make a binary subdivision between those two points. And so on...

But honestly, I guess it is faster to calculate all points a a higher resolution without any recursive loops or subdivisions. Especially if you are using multithread programming.

Comment: Thank you! But what I'm after is to find out the smallest step in O(1). I made question more explicit.